# How Do I simulate pressing enter with querySelectorAll in a single line

Tags: javascript

I have edited the value of an input text like below:

`document.body.querySelectorAll("*[id$='WE0234']")[0].value = '30000'`

Then, How can I simulate event to SELECT and then to press ENTER on this input text? I want to do it in 2 lines like below.

I want to do something like this..

`document.body.querySelectorAll("*[id$='WE0234']")[0].SELECT_TEXT`

`document.body.querySelectorAll("*[id$='WE0234']")[0].PRESS_ENTER`

Comment: What do you mean with simulate to press ENTER? Make an action onPress the ENTER botton? And why a single line?

Comment: Sorry, new to javascript. I want to simulate an event of press enter (13). I want to do it in a single line because I am calling or executing the javascript command from python/robotframework. Do you have any suggestion.

Comment: Hmm i do not know whats robot framework so you will have to wait for someone with that knowledge, sorry :(

Comment: I have edited the question. Maybe you understand now what I am trying to do.. This question has nothing to do with python or robotframework. Just I want to do it line by line